# Reading a file into List(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have a problem with understanding ILists:

There is a sequence of structured records given in a textfile with fixed sizes.The simple function "GetFileReferences" is reading a single line and map the processed fields against a set of mapping fields such like character length defined in clsFileImportMappingClass.
:) Now, In best case, GetFileReferences  returns a Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of clsFileImportMappingClass)) which covers the given file and containing n elements of List(Of clsFileImportMappingClass) in each line.

Example 1):
File Sample1.CSV may contain the following lines

1. 10        1
2. 20        1

GetFileReferences is returning the correct result:

1. Key: 10 | FIELD:02   | CONTENTS: 1
2. Key: 20 | FIELD:02   | CONTENTS: 3

Example 2)
File Sample2.CSV containing now following lines:

1. 10  1
2. 10  2
3. 20  3

Tracing the processed file and vars again would show the following output.

Wrong:

```
Mapping 1-> 1. Key: 10 | FIELD:02 | CONTENTS: 2 (not 1 as expected) 
Mapping 1-> 2. Key: 10 | FIELD:02 | CONTENTS: 2 
Mapping 2-> 3. Key: 20 | FIELD:02 | CONTENTS: 3
```

Does anyone may have an idea why lines with identical mappings are ignored.
I have chosen the following approach to map a single line in a file where as the mapping is stored in a database:

```
Public Function MappingTheCSVLine(ByVal csvline As String, ByVal iMapping As List(Of clsFileImportMappingClass)) As List(Of clsEDI_FileImportMappingClass)

    Dim TList As New List(Of clsFileImportMappingClass)

    For row As Integer = 0 To iMapping.Count - 1
        Dim oField As New clsFileImportMappingClass
        oField = iMapping(row)

        If oField.USED Then
            Dim fldLength As Int32
            Dim fldFROM As Int32

            fldLength = oField.FLD_LENGTH
            fldFROM = oField.FLD_FROM

            Dim sField As String
            sField = csvline.Substring(fldFROM - 1, fldLength)

            If sField.Contains("""") Then
                sField.Replace("""", String.Empty)
            End If
            oField.Contents = Trim(CType(IIf(sField IsNot Nothing, sField, ""), String))

            TList.Add(oField)
        End If

    Next

    'TList is returning the mapped line completely as desired

    Return TList
End Function





Public Function GetFileReferences(ByVal FileMapping As List(Of clsFileImportMappingClass)) As Dictionary (Of Integer, List(Of clsFileImportMappingClass))

    Dim EOL As String = vbCrLf

    Dim strText As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_FileName)

    Dim _lines As String()
    _lines = Split(strText, EOL)

    Dim tDictMapping As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of clsFileImportMappingClass))
    tDictMapping = getMappingToDictionary(FileMapping)

    'The object FileMapping is a List(Of clsFileImportMappingClass) and is providing general information of the file
    'which is to read. Mapping information like field lengths is stored in our local database.
    'In other words: File Mapping is the presentation of the structure of each file column described in a specific datatable.
    ' 
    'Example 2)
    '
    'File Sample2.CSV may contain following sample lines
    '10     1
    '10     2
    '20     3

    Dim FileRefs As New Dictionary (Of Integer, List(Of clsFileImportMappingClass))
    Dim ij As Integer : ij = 0
    For row As Integer = 0 To _lines.Count - 1
        Dim Key As String = ""
        Dim line As String : line = ""
        Dim sField As String : sField = ""
        line = _lines(row)

        Dim sKey As String = LTrim(RTrim(line.Substring(0, 3)))

         If tDictMapping.ContainsKey(Key) Then
            Console.WriteLine(line)
            Console.WriteLine("Schlüssel-Wert:" & Key)

            Dim oList As New List(Of clsFileImportMappingClass)
            oList = MappingTheCSVLine(_lines(row), tDictMapping(Key))
            tFileRefs.Add(ij, oList)
            DebugItems(FileRefs(ij))
            ij += 1
        End If

    Next

    Console.WriteLine("")

    '
    'Looping the local temporary var FileRefs again is giving me now the following, annoying wrong output. The Mapping is correct, meanwhile.
    '

    'KEY: 10 | FIELD:02 | CONTENTS: 2 (should be 1 !!!!!!!)
    'KEY: 10 | FIELD:02 | CONTENTS: 2
    'KEY: 20 | FIELD:02 | CONTENTS: 3

    For ji As Integer = 0 To FileRefs.Count - 1

        DebugItems(tFileRefs(ji))

    Next

    'Applying the same mapping, in my case would the mapping be with ID 10, always leads to the same scenario where the last mapped line is overwriting the other pairs (to any different lines).

    Return tFileRefs

End Function

Private Sub DebugItems(ByVal RefsList As List(Of clsFileImportMappingClass))
    For col As Integer = 0 To RefsList.Count - 1
        Dim sout As String : sout = ""
        Dim obj As New clsFileImportMappingClass : obj = RefsList(col)
        sout = "Key: " & obj.Key & " | FIELD:" & obj.FIELD_NR & " | CONTENTS: " & obj.CONTENTS.ToString
        Console.WriteLine(sout)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: There are tools like CSVHelper which will read your file, parse it, type the data and put it in a collection for you.

Comment: thank you, for the quick anwswer and yes, CSVHelper is a way to go. But this is not a solution for my problem and does not explain why the contents of the last line with mapping 10 is over writing all other similiar pair of lines ( as shown in the source code ) Maybe any other approach ? :(